# Windows 8 app Json parser C#

Tags: c#, windows, json

I am having trouble creating a button click event that reads json from a site and then pulls a certain item from it.  Say the Json is

```
{
  "Items":[
    { "Name":"Apple", "Price":12.3 },
    { "Name":"Grape", "Price":3.21 }
   ],
  "Date":"21/11/2010"
}
```

and on the button click it would only pull the names of the fruits.

This is using Visual Studios and XAML/C#

Comment: Do not reinvent the wheel. Use [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

Comment: [Json2C#](http://json2csharp.com/) with Json.NET

Comment: Alright I have the classes, but I'm trying to figure out the code to create a list of just the names.  how would i go about doing that?